# Create a toggle for users to place markers in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, markers

I am working on an webpage that uses Leaflet. The users can currently place a marker on the map when they click a specific area. I was wondering if there is a way to add a toggle so that the user can enable and disable placing markers when they click on the map.

I can't seem to find anything, but I could have missed it. I am new to HTML and Leaflet so I apologize if this has a simple solution. Below is my current HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css" 
          integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI=" crossorigin="" 
          />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256- 
            WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM=" crossorigin=""></script>
    <style>
        #map {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 1)

        L.tileLayer('https://api.maptiler.com/maps/streets-v2/{z}/{x}/{y}.png? 
                  key=TUHtC4pfxR178kXfCmqg', {
                  attribution: '<a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" 
                  target="_blank">&copy; MapTiler</a> <a 
                  href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">&copy; 
                  OpenStreetMap contributors</a>'
        }).addTo(map)

        var markerOptions = {
            draggable: false
        }

        map.on("click", function (e){
            var marker = new L.Marker([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng], 
                         markerOptions).addTo(map);
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For creating toggle button control you can use `L.EasyButton` Leaflet plugin (see https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton).

To differentiate between toggle states you can for example set button background color to yellow when adding markers is activated.

Relevant part of the code could then look something like this:
**CSS**

```
.disable-markers-active {
  background-color: #FFFF99 !important;
}
```

**JS**

```
var markerOptions = {
  draggable: false
}

function createMarkerOnClick(evt) {
  L.marker([evt.latlng.lat, evt.latlng.lng], markerOptions).addTo(map);
}
  
var toggle = L.easyButton({
  states: [{
    stateName: 'enable-markers',
    icon: 'fa-map-marker',
    title: 'Enable markers on click',
    onClick: function(control) {
      control.state('disable-markers');
      map.on('click', createMarkerOnClick);
    }
  }, {
    icon: 'fa-map-marker',
    stateName: 'disable-markers',
    title: 'Disable markers on click',
    onClick: function(control) {
      control.state('enable-markers');
      map.off('click', createMarkerOnClick);
    }
  }]
});
toggle.addTo(map);
```